# Count click on button or link and store in cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

So here is the deal. I have a div I want to show the 3rd time the same user clicks a button. I want to store the clicks in a cookie and count the clicks. Then when the button is clicked for the 3rd time I want to show the div.

I use jquery on my site and already use this http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt  to set other cookies, but I must admit I am a javascript newbee to say the least

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var clickCount = parseInt($.cookie('clickCount'), 10);

   clickCount++;

   if (clickCount >= 3) {
       $('div').show();
   }

   $.cookie('clickCount', clickCount, { path: '/' });   

});
```

Comment: I just get a cookie with the value 'clicked'. No count number?

Comment: Hey Alex - no I did not. I am still a new user here so I can't vote. Besides the problem was I did not have a css selected included. So when I set #button instead of button it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I was hoping you could fill in the blanks for the selector. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @Thomas, you can [vote answers up](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges), but not down, as yet (requires a reputation of 125+).

Comment: Can I post an additional question? How do I set a path for the click count cookie to be "/" no matter what url the button is on?